# Multiplying elementwise over final axis of two arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-einsum

Given a 3d array and a 2d array,

```
a = np.arange(10*4*3).reshape((10,4,3))
b = np.arange(30).reshape((10,3))
```

How can I run elementwise-multiplication across the final axis of each, resulting in `c` where `c` has the shape `.shape` as `a`?  I.e.

```
c[0] = a[0] * b[0]
c[1] = a[1] * b[1]
# ...
c[i] = a[i] * b[i]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any sum-reduction involved, a simple `broadcasting` would be really efficient after extending `b` to `3D` with [`np.newaxis/None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) -

```
a*b[:,None,:] # or simply a*b[:,None]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [531]: a = np.arange(10*4*3).reshape((10,4,3))
     ...: b = np.arange(30).reshape((10,3))
     ...: 

In [532]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ik->ijk', a, b) #@Brad Solomon's soln
     ...: %timeit a*b[:,None]
     ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 µs per loop

In [525]: a = np.random.rand(100,100,100)

In [526]: b = np.random.rand(100,100)

In [527]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ik->ijk', a, b)
     ...: %timeit a*b[:,None]
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 ms per loop

In [528]: a = np.random.rand(400,400,400)

In [529]: b = np.random.rand(400,400)

In [530]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ik->ijk', a, b)
     ...: %timeit a*b[:,None]
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 128 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 94.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: @BradSolomon That's right. Added timings to confirm those.

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.einsum`:

```
c = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ijk', a, b)
```

Quick check:

```
print(np.allclose(c[0], a[0] * b[0]))
print(np.allclose(c[1], a[1] * b[1]))
print(np.allclose(c[-1], a[-1] * b[-1]))
# True
# True
# True
```